# How can I read and write text files using the windows api

Tags: c++, winapi

There are many similar questions, but mine is a bit different. Mine involves a Windows GUI. I am using an open file dialog or an "`OPENFILENAME`". I want to get the dialog result as OK when the user clicks the OK button and then open a text encoded file. I have done it in Java, but the UI looks weird. So I am not sure whether or not people would like it. I want to learn C++ as well, so I need some help. I have a text box called "`hWndEdit`" in the `WM_COMMAND` message inside my program. After opening, the text in the file is supposed to be displayed in the textBox I have specified. I have defined the function in a header file with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void OpenFile()
{
        OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
        HWND hwnd = nullptr;              // owner window
        HANDLE hf;              // file handle

        // Initialize OPENFILENAME
        ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
        ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
        // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
        // use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
        ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
        ofn.lpstrFilter = L"NoteRecorder Notes\0(*.recnote)\0Text\0(*.txt)\0";
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
        ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
        ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
        ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
        ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

        // Display the Open dialog box. 

        if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
        {
            hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
                GENERIC_READ,
                0,
                (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                (HANDLE)NULL);
        }
}
```

Then I call it from my `WM_COMMAND` message:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
switch (wParam)
{
case 12:
OpenFile();
break;
}
```

But when the user presses the OK button in the `OPENFILENAME`, it doesn't read any text from the file. How can I accomplish this?

And I want to write files with a save file dialog. Tell me how to do that as well.

Comment: Which part of this code is supposed to read anything from the file? All you are doing is opening it for reading

Comment: Maybe you want to use [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile)

Comment: I question if you really want to read your text file using windows api functions directly instead of using c++ iostreams.

Comment: ***And I want to write files with a save file dialog. Tell me how to do that as well.*** That is probably a separate question. Although I suspect once you are able to read, writing is not that much different.

Comment: Your file dialog code is broken. And you should use C++ standard library to read the file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How do I fix it?

Comment: Read the documentation. But then don't fix it, use IFileDialog instead. As the documentation will tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of the functions [`GetOpenFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea) and [`GetSaveFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getsavefilenamea) is to provide you with the filename that the user selected. However, doing the actual File Input and Output is a different issue. You can use the standard C/C++ library for that or you can use the Windows API functions, such as [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea), [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) and [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile).

Since you seem to already be using the function `CreateFile`, it would make sense to call `ReadFile` after verifying that the function call to `CreateFile` succeeded (i.e. that it did not return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`). After reading the data, you can add a terminating null character to the data (you should make sure that the memory buffer is large enough) and then pass it to the [`SetDlgItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdlgitemtexta) function (if the text box is in a dialog box) or [`SetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtexta) function.

Comment: Now, how do you think I can do that? I would like some extra help please.

Comment: @user16709023: Which part do you have trouble with? Getting the data to the file? Or sending the data to your text box? I have provided links to the documentation of all of the functions that I mentioned. Is there something specific that you don't understand in the documentation? Or don't you have a specific question, because you are completely lost? If it is the latter, then you should probably buy [a good book on C++ programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/12149471) before attempting to do this.

Comment: @user16709023: Also, here is a [link to the official Microsoft tutorial on Win32 programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows). If your C++ knowledge is insufficient to follow that tutorial, then you should first buy a book on learning how to program in C++.

Comment: I dropped this project. I did it in C# and I don't plan to learn Windows Gui in C++ anymore. I decided. NET is the way to go